# Validation doesn't check rules

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I use the jQuery Validate plugin to check forms on website. Here is a piece of my HTML form for checking

```
<form id ="formCharacteristics" align="center">
    <dl>
        <dt style="text-align:left; margin-left:120px;"><label for="cpuname">CPU name</label></dt>
        <dd><input type="text" id="cpuname" placeholder="Intel 8086"></dd>                 
    <div align="right" style="margin-right:30px">
        <button id="buttonSubmitCharacteristics" type="button" onclick = "AddCPU()" >Done</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="HideMessage()">Back</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

And here is piece of JavaScript code, it invokes validation before Ajax posting

```
AddCPU(){
    var form = $('#formCharacteristics');
    if(!form.valid())
        return;
    var CPUname = $('input #cpuname');
    ....
}
```

Validation works properly on other forms, but on this form it doesn't check any rule. I don't use same form ID and input ID.
Here is code for specifing rules

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
$('#formCharacteristics').validate({ 
    rules:{ 
        cpuname: { 
            required: true, 
            maxlength: 30, 
            minlength: 4 
            } 
        } 
    });
......

)};
```

Comment: Where is the code that specifies the intended validations for `cpuname`?  As far as I can see, the form is valid because there are no rules applied to `cpuname`

Comment: You can't call `form.valid()` unless you've previously called `form.validate()` to specify the rules and other validation options. And the validation plugin requires elements to have names, not just IDs.

Comment: @Barmar, *"I use a Validation plugin"* - based on the code, it's not even clear which plugin he's talking about so I'm not sure why you tagged it with [tag:jquery-validate].

Comment: @Sparky `form.valid()` is part of that plugin, although I suppose it's possible other plugins have a similar method.

Comment: Here is code for specifing rules
`$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#formCharacteristics').validate({
        rules:{
            cpuname: {
                required: true,
                maxlength: 30,
                minlength: 4
            }
        }
    });
});`

Comment: @Barmar, indeed they do.

Comment: @MasterUZ, please use the "edit" link to fix your OP.  Thanks.

Comment: @MasterUZ, and as @Barmar has already stated, you must have a `name` attribute on each input and the `rules` object can only reference these names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Code:

```
$('#formCharacteristics').validate({ 
    rules: { 
        cpuname: { // <- this is the NAME attribute
            required: true, 
            maxlength: 30,
            ....
```

For the jQuery Validate plugin to work properly, your `input` **must** contain the same `name` as specified in the `rules` object...

```
<input type="text" name="cpuname" id="cpuname" ....
```